# When to use dot and arrow operator in C++ pair?

Tags: c++, stl

I have written the following code for a vector in C++ STL:

```
vector<pair< int,pair<int,int>> > v;
vector<pair< int,pair<int,int>> >::iterator it;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        v.push_back(make_pair(a[i]+a[j],pair<int,int>(i,j)));

for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
    cout<<(it->first)<<(it->second.first);
```

There is no problem with this code. It works. What I want to know is why we are using arrow operator to access vector pair and dot operator to access pair inside pair?

How can I know confidently when to use what. What is the logic here?

PS: **a** is some array with **n** elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following code sample, `it` is of type `iterator` as you declared up top.

```
for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
    cout << it->first << it->second.first;
```

`vector::iterator` is a class in which the arrow operator is overloaded to return a *reference* to an item in the vector you are looping over.  That's just how iterators work.

If you want a more traditional 'dot' operator iteration, this would suffice:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    cout<<(v[i].first) <<  (v[i].second.first);
}
```

Or even better:

```
for (auto &item : v)
{
    std::cout << item.first << item.second.first;
}
```

I have no idea what `sc` and `fc` are in your code.  Maybe that's an alias for `first` and `second` ?

Comment: So you mean when I am not using iterator I will have to use dot operator, else when I am using it then arrow operator?

Comment: Yep, pretty much.  See my amended answer on how to iterate with the dot operator.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention, they are first and second.

Comment: But why is it that I have to use the dot operator always to access the pair inside pair part? Is it something to do with using make_pair and not using it?

Comment: What did you do to make `sc` and `fc` valid members of the vector's iterator class. It doesn't make any sense in your question unless you did something weird like `#define fc first`.

Comment: Of course I did #define fc first for writing less code. Sorry for the confusion. I will update.

Comment: The iterator's arrow operator returns a reference, not a pointer, to an instance of a `pair< int,pair<int,int>>`.   Hence, the dot operator to get to the inner member.

Comment: It's not good programming practice in C++ to redefine the language by aliasing keywords and standard names. Think of it like this.  You managed to confuse **me**, a veteran programmer, with only seven lines of sample code.  Imagine what the other guy on your team will think who has less experience than I do and he needs to debug your code.

Comment: Yes sure but its just I am doing Competetive programming and it requires all this for speed.

Comment: @BaqirKhan How long does it take you to type `first`? If you're worried about taking too long to type that, you need to work on your typing speed, not use macro abuse. Macros like these should speed up your typing by about 2 minutes at most.

Comment: The fundamental problem with competitive programming, code golf, and hacker challenge sites is that they unintentionally encourage some of the worst programming practices.

Comment: It does take quite some time when you have to write first and second many time.@FeiXiang,
And @selbie, it just depends on the mood. When I am coding a large scalable application, I write the code in a very intuitive manner so that it is easily understandable.

Comment: @BaqirKhan I can do about 60 WPM, which is very slow compared to other programmers. Lets say your program is 100 lines (competitive programs I write are usually much shorter), and 75% of the lines have one `first` (75% is about the portion of lines in my programs that don't consist of a single curly bracket). That means you will save about a minute with that macro. You're better off investing in other stuff instead of macros like these and make your code more readable at the same time. Another benefit to not using these macros is that you end up with good habits which will help in the future.

Comment: Got it.         Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely also mention the range-based for loop variant as an example, as this makes all the ugliness go away.